# Implementing dup2 in xv6

Tags: c, operating-system, dup2, xv6

I'm taking an OS class and we have to implement `dup2()` in xv6. The code I've written should theoretically work, but, when I try to execute tests, it doesn't pass all of them.

This is my system call:

```
int sys_dup2(void) {
  int oldfd, newfd;
  struct file *oldf, *newf;  

  struct proc *curproc = myproc();

  if (argfd(0, &oldfd, &oldf) < 0)
    return -1;
  if (argfd(1, &newfd, &newf) < 0)
    return -1;

  if (oldfd == newfd)
    return newfd;
  if (newfd != 0)
    fileclose(newf);

  filedup(oldf);
  curproc->ofile[newfd] = oldf;
  return newfd;
}
```

The tests that doesn't pass are:

```
if (dup2 (1,4) != 4)
  printf (2, "dup2 not working with existing fd.\n");

printf (4, "This message outputs on terminal.\n");

if (dup2 (4,6) != 6)
  printf (2, "dup2 not working with existing fd (2).\n");
```

I'm thinking that the problem is linked with `argfd()` because when I try to debug with GDB I find `oldfd` equals to some random number.

This is xv6's `argfd()`:

```
static int
argfd(int n, int *pfd, struct file **pf)
{
  int fd;
  struct file *f;

  if(argint(n, &fd) < 0)
    return -1;
  if(fd < 0 || fd >= NOFILE || (f=myproc()->ofile[fd]) == 0)
    return -1;
  if(pfd)
    *pfd = fd;
  if(pf)
    *pf = f;
  return 0;
}
```

I leave the xv6's functions `argint()`, `fetchint()` and `filedup()` to better understand the code above.

```
int
argint(int n, int *ip)
{
  return fetchint((myproc()->tf->esp) + 4 + 4*n, ip);
}
```

```
int
fetchint(uint addr, int *ip)
{
  struct proc *curproc = myproc();

  if(addr >= curproc->sz || addr+4 > curproc->sz)
    return -1;
  *ip = *(int*)(addr);
  return 0;
}
```

```
struct file*
filedup(struct file *f)
{
  acquire(&ftable.lock);
  if(f->ref < 1)
    panic("filedup");
  f->ref++;
  release(&ftable.lock);
  return f;
}
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: What do `argint` and `filedup` do?  In particular, what is the intention of your hardcoded arguments 0 and 1 to your `argfd` calls?

Comment: Hi! I edited the question to show the related functions. `argfd()` is used to take an argument from the stack during a system call, so the hardcoded 0 and 1 means to take the 0 and the 1 arguments. That should be `(int oldfd, int newfd)` passed to the function from userspace.

Comment: `if (newfd != 0) fileclose(newf)` looks suspicious.  You are supposed to be able to dup over file descriptor 0; that's how standard input redirection works.  Conversely, a nonzero value may very well refer to a file that's not open; that too is supposed to work.  In that case I suppose `newf` would be null, and what does `fileclose(NULL)` do?

Comment: Maybe the test was meant to be `if (newf != 0)`?

Comment: Actually, wait: if `newfd` isn't open then won't `argfd` fail?  And then you'll return failure instead of dup'ing as you should.  It's not clear in the test if fd 4 is already open at that point, or not.

Comment: Finally, one of the features of `dup2` is supposed to be that it closes the old fd and opens the new one atomically.  You don't hold any locks between closing `newf` and updating `curproc->ofile[newfd]`; what if some other thread opens a file in the meantime?  It might coincidentally get `newfd`, and then you conflict.

Comment: `if (newfd != 0) fileclose(newf)` is to test if the file is already open; if it is, then close it, so newf should never be NULL. Thinking about it, I don't think that testing `newfd` makes sense!

Comment: In the test 4 has never been opened, so the test is incorrect you say?

Comment: Whether fd 4 is open or not, `dup2(1,4)` is a valid use of the `dup2` call and should succeed, returning 4.  I think your implementation returns -1.  So the test is a correct test, and your code genuinely fails it.

Answer (score 1):

`dup2(oldfd, newfd)` is supposed to work whether `newfd` is open or not.  It looks to me like `argfd` will fail if called with a file descriptor that is not open (presumably the corresponding entry in the `myproc()->ofile` table would be null), in which case your function just returns -1, which is wrong.  So you won't be able to use `argfd` to validate the `newfd` argument.  Maybe there's some other standard function available, or maybe you just have to do the same checks for yourself.

It's not clear in the test if fd 4 is supposed to already be open or not (does "existing fd" mean the old one or the new one?) but if it's not, then it does seem like your implementation would fail the test.

The test `if (newfd != 0)` also looks wrong; 0 is a valid file descriptor (standard input), so it shouldn't be treated differently. In fact you need to `dup2(fd, 0)` every time you use `<` input redirection in your shell.  I'm not sure what you meant to put here, but it probably has to change anyway when you redo the validation.

Finally, I don't know what xv6's rules are for concurrency and threading, but I'm worried about races and TOCTOU bugs.  You don't hold any locks between checking the validity/status of the file descriptors and doing your actual work.

What if another thread of this process closes `oldfd` or `newd` after you test it, and deallocates the `struct file`?  Then your `struct file *` is dangling.

What if another thread is accessing `newfd` while all this is going on?  The `dup2` operation is supposed to be atomic, so `write(newfd, data, sz)` in another thread should write either to the original `newfd` or the dup'd `oldfd`, but it should not fail with `EBADF`.  Which is what will happen in your code if that write should occur in the window between `fileclose(newf)` and `curproc->ofile[newfd] = oldf;`.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with `newfd` being invalid. I used `argint()` to catch the fd and then looked at the `curproc->ofile[newfd]`